# Visa passport update

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, australia

I am from India and I applied for a skilled professional visa for Australia  with my old passport but it didn't have a spouse name on it. So I applied to add it and had issues with a new passport. I informed DIBP regarding this, but I got the visa on my old passport only. Now I have informed DIBP to update the passport details on their end... but haven't received any reply till now.

Just need to confirm if I can travel by taking along both old and new passports... in case I don't get any confirmation from DIBP regarding the update of my passport details.

Comment: Can you add: 1) your nationality, 2) the type & country of the visa that you applied for, and 3) hat you mean by "updated the change of your passport". Finally, how could you have your passport changed while your visa application was in progress? Typically, this means turning in the passport at some embassy.

Comment: I am from India , visa is Skilled provisional visa for Australia .

Comment: i applied for visa with my old passport bt it didnt had spouse name on it . So i applied to add it and was issues with a new passport . I informed DIBP regarding this ..but i got the visa on my old passport only. now i have  informed DIBP to update the passport details ..on their end ...but haven,t received any reply till now . just need to confirm if can trave by taking along both old and new passport ... in case i dont get any confirmation from DIBP regarding the updation of my passport details.

Comment: @Singh, please put that info into your question using the 'edit' button. Nobody wants to chase the needed info by reading comments!